# react-select default value did not work with props

Tags: reactjs

As in the title. I have been used the react-select component and I pass props to it as the default value. but it did not show. why did this happen? even when I pass string to it like this defaultValue="aa"

this is the sandbox for my code:
[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-golick-4x5gyf?file=/src/SelectItemComp.js:399-402)

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: i expect the value of b to show as chosen option from beginning (when user did not open select option yet)   @Lin Du

Comment: you should have pass the `defaultValue` among the `options` you provided to `Select` component

Answer (score 1):

The `defaultValue` should be the `Option` type, see [StateManager Props](https://react-select.com/props#statemanager-props)

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

// it should be
<SelectItemComp b={options[0]} options={options} />

// not
<SelectItemComp b='chocolate' options={options} />
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76677613-rl9vq7)

You can find the official example [home#getting-started](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started)

Comment: oh I dont know that thanks. so I can't do what i expected ? or you think there is another way

Answer (score -1):

Please Check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-elion-zvcf3g?file=/src/SelectItemComp.js). I've made some changes might help you.

```js
import SelectItemComp from "./SelectItemComp";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { id: 0, value: "default", label: "Select an option" },
    { id: 1, value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { id: 2, value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { id: 3, value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SelectItemComp options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const SelectItemComp = (props) => {
  const { options } = props;
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(options[0]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const selectedItem = e.value;
    setSelectedItem(selectedItem);
  };

  console.log("default", selectedItem);

  return (
    <Select
      defaultValue={options[0]}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
    />
  );
};

// This might help you if you don't pass any options as props to SelectItemComp
// Happy coding
SelectItemComp.defaultProps = {
  options: [{ id: 0, value: "default", label: "Select an option" }]
};

export default SelectItemComp;
```

You need to include default value in the options array. You don't have to passe it separately as a prop. and for simplicity i added default props if you forgot to pass options props as param to SelectItemComp component  .

Comment: but that is not how my code work . as you can see the default value i was sent is not part of options is a sprat variable (in my actual code the b value is come from an api ) so i can't take your code as a solution for me